# Исключения при удалении указателей в c++

Tags: c++

Необходимо найти способ, чтобы по любому возможному пути выполнения программы (включая возможные исключения) для каждого выполненного `new` выполнялся `delete` (и `delete` не выполнялся ни для чего лишнего).
Использую конструкцию:

```
bool *a = new bool[n];
int *k = new int[m];

try {
    // сам код
}
catch(...) {
    delete [] a;
    delete [] k;
}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой:

1. Если, например, `new` на первой строчке бросит исключение, то я вызову
   `delete` для неинициализированного указателя.
2. Если `delete` на предпоследней строке бросит исключение, то я
   остальную выделенную память не освобожу.

Как это исправить?

Comment: «Чтобы сдать задачу» — а другой причины для этого вы не видите?

Comment: RAII принципиально использовать не хочется?

Comment: Используйте `std::vector` вместо ручного управления памятью. К тому же для `bool` размер будет в ~8 раз меньше исходного варианта.

Comment: @alexolut, что-то не похоже на дубликат - там же не про исключения...

Comment: @Qwertiy а причем тут я? :)

Comment: @alexolut, не при чём :) Надо было смотреть на подставляемое имя перед нажатием tab)))

Comment: @Arhad, см. выше.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если при вызове `new` состоится исключение, присваивания не будет, так что в указателе будет `nullptr`. По станадрту `C++`, `delete nullptr` ничего не делает и отрабатывает корректно. Так что:

```
Type my_ugly_pointer=nullptr;
try
{ 
    my_ugly_pointer=new ...
}
catch(...)
{
}
delete my_ugly_pointer;
```

Comment: Эээ, а почему в коде ТС в указателе будет nullptr? Он же вроде не иницилизирован? Или вы имеете в виду ваш код?

Comment: @VladD мой код, у меня же как раз это и сделано.

Comment: А, понял, сорри.

Comment: А что делать, если на одном из первых delete  состоится исключение? Остальные же не будут удалены

Comment: @Parket, вы или используете умный указатель, или вкладываете блоки исключений матрешкой.

Comment: @Parket, а с чего бы в delete быть исключению, если только ты память не попортил.

Comment: @Qwertiy, delete не выбрасывает исключений. За исключением случая, когда кто-то безголовый решит бросить исключение из деструктора. К счастью, это считается плохой практикой, а начиная с C++11 все деструкторы сделаны nothrow, что заставляет, в частрости, gcc, писать предупреждения.

Comment: @gbg, если испортить кусок памяти перед той, на которую указывает указатель, то, вероятно, что-нибудь грохнется. Или если попытаться освободить память, которая не выделялась.

Comment: @Qwertiy грохнется, но это будет уже SEGFAULT, а не исключение С++.

Answer (score 4):

Запихните свои new в try.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133056/what-happens-when-i-call-delete-on-an-uninitialized-pointer-in-c

Кроме того к вашим услугам [RAII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [умные указатели](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C).

Answer (score 2):

Вам уже дали совет "использовать умный указатель". Показываю (вариант C++14):

```
#include <memory>

using std::make_unique;

try
{
  auto pt = std::make_unique<Type>();
  auto pt2 = std::make_unique<Type2>();
  ...
}
catch(...)
{
}
```

Если в конструкторе `pt2` будет исключение, `pt` будет уничтожен умным указателем `unique_ptr`;

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` устаревший класс. Не надо его использовать.

Comment: А с `std::unique_ptr` лучше использовать `std::make_unique`. Меньше аллокаций, и дублирования имени типа.

Comment: `std::make_unique` это `c++14`. И зачем плодить ответы?

Comment: @alexolut куча народу сидит на 98 стандарте и никуда с него не слезет еще лет 5.

Comment: Я не о том, что не стоит упоминать старый Стандарт в принципе, а о необходимости делать это в **отдельном** ответе. Можно ведь добавить в существующий и уменьшить кол-во лишней информации на странице. Или это борьба за "лайки"?

Comment: @alexolut Я предпочитаю не смешивать разные ответы в один. Тем более, что комментарии к каждому ответу получились разные - в совете с try-catch - одно обсуждение, в совете с unique_ptr - другое, не релевантное ни к чему другому.

Answer (score 1):

Вам уже дали совет "использовать умный указатель". Показываю (вариант C++98):

```
#include <memory>



try
{
  std::auto_ptr<Type> pt( new Type );
  std::auto_ptr<Type> pt2( new Type );
  ...
}
catch(...)
{
}
```

Если в конструкторе `pt2` будет исключение, `pt` будет уничтожен умным указателем `auto_ptr`;